# Как в bootsrap 4 удалить все breakpoint?

Tags: scss, bootstrap4

Как удалить вообще все breakpoints из Bootstrap 4.

Например, в стандартной сборке есть классы **"col", "col-xs",  "col-sm"** и т.д.

Из них мне нужен только один **"col"** . Все остальные хочу удалить. Аналогично и с другими классами, которые создаются под все брейкпоинты.

Подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: а если не секрет, зачем это надо?

Comment: Размер итогового css уменьшается примерно на 40%. Это ещё до сжатия.

А такое количество брейкпоинтов мне не нужно, я их не использовал вообще. Вёрстка простая работает нормально и на мобиле и на деске.

Comment: Зачем тогда вообще Бутстрап использовать? Смысл-то этой библиотеки как раз и заключается в гибкой сетке, которая меняется в зависимости от брейкпоинтов.

Comment: Не во всех проектах нужны все стандартные брейкпоинты бутстрапа.

А все остальные стили для таблиц, меню, и т.д. писать самому еслия не хочу брейкпоинты использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось сделать вот таким образом:

Переопределил стандартные переменные своими и скомпилировал.

Было так

```
  $grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
) !default;

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px
) !default;
```

стало так:

```
    $grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0
);

$container-max-widths: (
);
```

Практически всё лишнее удалилось. Осталось лишь 3-4 упоминания класса -xs.